# Stop CocoaPod podspec settings applying to client build?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoapods

I'm the author of [zipzap](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap) working on fixing some [podspec issues](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap/issues/71).

In particular I've found that setting the XCCONFIG settings on the podspec results in that setting propagating to both client and library builds. This is due to CocoaPods generating a `Pods.xcconfig` that contains the podspec's XCCONFIG settings and then applying it to the client `xcodeproj` as well as the umbrella pod `xcodeproj`.

I do however see a `Pods-zipzap-Private.xcconfig` which contains a copy of those settings -- how do I restrict my podspec settings to that config file only? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Could you please provide example of settings you apply in XCCONFIG?

Comment: In the podspec JSON format:

    "xcconfig": {
        "CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD": "c++11",
        "CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY": "libc++",
        "GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS": "NO",
        "OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS": "-fno-exceptions"
      }

Comment: Was [this commit](https://github.com/pixelglow/ZipZap/commit/d2d845437af5f4d70568b1276ba60764c5278e16) the solution?